# How to edit and invert keyframes on an object in Maya using python?

Tags: python, animation, maya

I want to copy the animation from one object to another, then invert it so that the two objects do exactly opposite actions. Currently, the way I do it manually is to select the curve that I want to mirror in the graph editor, copy it to my second object, then select the curve and change the position by typing "*=-1" into the value at the top. This inverts the entire curve and offsets the animation. I would like to try to automate this using python.

I have tried copying and pasting the keys using the code below:

import maya.cmds as cmds

def transfer_animation(obj_a, obj_b, pTargetAttribute):
#copies the Translate X keyframes from the first object selected
cmds.copyKey(obj_a, animation='objects', option='keys', attribute=pTargetAttribute)
#adds the copied keys to the translate X channel of the second object selected
cmds.pasteKey(obj_b, animation='objects', option='replaceCompletely', attribute=pTargetAttribute)

sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)

transfer_animation(sel[0], sel[1], 'translateX')

While this works to effectively copy over the attribute I want to copy over, I can't figure out how to set it to actually complete the final step of inverting the keyframes. Adding "valueChange*=-1" to the pasteKey line returned a syntax error, as did most other configurations I tried for valueChange. Admittedly I am very new to python coding in Maya, so I'm sure this is a very basic solution.